# Causal Inference With a Nominal Treatment

Tags: categorical-data, causality, matching

I am working with a treatment that has three nominal (I suppose these could be considered ordered) values:

0 = no mediation,
1 = failed mediation,
2 = successful mediation,

For the purposes of the project I am working on, "failed mediation" is the treatment of interest. In particular, I am interested in whether failed mediation attempts cause warring actors to pursue violence and abandon diplomacy over the course of a conflict.

However, I am concerned how this will work in practice. For example, if I approached this using matching, I would match cases of failed mediation with...? This is where it gets confusing for me. Would I create a new binary treatment variable (1 = failed mediation, 0 = else)? If so, do I run any risk with lumping cases of "no mediation" and "successful mediation" together in the control group? If so, it feels like I am creating a control group that contains substantively different information as it relates to treatment.

Alternatively, I could drop cases of "no mediation" and have "successful mediation" serve as the control group, but I feel like this creates a selection bias issue.

Comment: It depends on your research hypothesis, which is not spelled out. Can you elaborate on the comparison(s) you want to make?

Comment: From what I understand you want to estimate effect of $x \rightarrow y$, where x is an ordered categorical variable. Have you considered [Bürkner & Charpentier](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/31943157/)?

Comment: Is this an observational study or a randomized trial? If an OS, do you have enough variables to adjust for to remove confounding, if not, do you have an instrument or a pre-treatment measure of the outcome? There are many way to estimate treatment effects that depend on the feature of your design, so please clarify this and let us know why simple existing approaches (like ANOVA) aren't working here.

Comment: @dimitriy Understanding the comparisons I want to make is kind of the issue I am struggling with. The paper is currently a collaborative one (early in the works) so the hypothesis is tentatively that failed mediation attempts cause warring parties in civil conflicts to pursue violence, rather than negotiation, as a method to end conflict. However, given that treatment is *failed* mediation, rather than mediation itself, I'm struggling to figure out how (and if I need) to make this treatment binary.

Comment: @Noah it is an observational study. There is a large literature on this, so we currently are thinking a sufficient number of confounders have been identified to incorporate into a model that seeks to estimate the causal impact of failed mediation efforts. This literature, however, hasn't really adopted best practices in causal inference so many controls in models are incorrect, no sensitivity analyses have been executed for unobserved confounding, etc. Many of the confounders are not categorical, and I haven't seen ANOVA used in this literature, so I'm unsure if its appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of turning your research idea into a hypothesis is that Violence(SM) > Violence(NM) > Violence(FM) or perhaps Violence(SM) > Violence(FM) > Effect(NM).

The first says that SM helps, NM leads to violence, and FM is worse than no mediation. The second says that FM is between SM and NM, but both cause violence to increase. You can define effects relative to the NM experience. These aren't the only options, just those that spring to my mind.

There aren't any nearest neighbor and propensity score matching estimators with multivalued treatments.

A good approach is:

Cattaneo, M. D. 2010. [Efficient semiparametric estimation of multivalued treatment effects under ignorability](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=4cccdea50b7d4d3e9d396fd34ea7c2e076012c93). Journal of Econometrics 155: 138–154.

He has older Stata and forthcoming R code [here](https://cattaneo.princeton.edu/software), with examples and replications files.

Stata has a slew of newer parametric [multivalued TE estimators](https://www.stata.com/manuals13/teteffectsmultivalued.pdf) (teffects ra, teffects ipw, teffects ipwra, and teffects aipw). These use regression adjustment, inverse-probability weighting, inverse-probability-weighted regression adjustment, and augmented inverse-probability weighting. All assume ignorability conditional on observed covariates. There are also a few other community-contributed commands that are mentioned in the documentation.

**There could well be other implementations and approaches that I am not aware of. I don't have deep expertise with these models.**

Comment: this looks extremely promising. Going to give this a look over the next couple of days. Thank you for sharing.